# Rest API to upload an image with customized metadata in office 365

Tags: php, rest, metadata, office365, sharepoint-online

My requirement is to upload an image with metadata, i used  FileRestAPI to upload, i want to upload the image with metadata information like city,zipcode,date,address,customer type.

Does it possible to upload the file content with customized metadata like above?

or

I can upload  files only with the predefined metadata information available in  Item.properties?

Another question

Does it possible to do a search operation in cloud/server based on above metadata information?

My Environment:

Windows application, PHP,Office 365.

Comment: Are you using client libraries for SharePoint Online?